# CKEditor com MVC5 e EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ckeditor

Eu coloquei o CKEditor no meu projeto. Ele funciona tudo belezinha, porém quando clico no botão *Save* ele retorna essee erro:

> Um valor possivelmente perigoso Request.Form foi detectado no cliente (Conteudo="`<p>
>   <span style="f...").`

PS: Já desabilitei o `RequestValidation` no `Web.Config`

Comment: Tente decorar a sua Action que recebe o post com o seguinte código: [ValidateInput(false)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque [`ValidateInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)(false) no método do seu `Controller`, exemplo:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(Noticia model)
{

}
```

Com isso ele não vai validar os seus `input` que enviaram ao seu `model` um `html`, que por padrão do MVC não pode.

Ou

Utilize [`AllowHtml`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/753483/Validate-Input-in-ASP-NET-MVC) como atributo da propriedade da sua `classe`, exemplo:

```
public class Noticia
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Texto { get; set; }
}
```

*Referências:*

- [Validate Input in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/753483/Validate-Input-in-ASP-NET-MVC)
- [ValidateInputAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)
- [AllowHtmlAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)